# Recompiling / Running Dynamic Shared Objects (DSO) on Windows

Tags: linux, unix, interop

I don't have much in the way of Unix/Linux experience but are wondering if it is possible in any way to run DSOs on Windows? Can these be recompiled so they will execute?

Thanks in advance for any pointers you can give me.

Dave.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: if we're talking about PHP extensions here, you can get the source code for the extension and recompile it for Windows if you have some form of Visual Studio installed on your computer. You can also find alot of precompiled PHP extensions at http://windows.php.net/

Comment: Not for PHP. For rendering extensions. We may be able to get hold of the source code in some cases and recompile. If we can't get the source code then what I'm hearing is there's not much hope? Thx

Comment: Unless there's something cygwin can do, I don't think so.

Comment: Doesn't look like it. Plus, I imagine there would be a small performance hit running through cygwin. Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: Cygwin is not a way to run native linux apps on Windows. You have to rebuild your application from source if you want it to run on Windows. see `http://www.cygwin.com/`